# postgresql-8.4 text search is not working

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, full-text-search

I tried to implement full/partial text search using  postgresql-8.4 & django

```
SELECT * FROM fts WHERE body_tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('english','hello welcome')
```

Available records are

```
'hello world'
'hello old world'
'hi welcome'
```

But the result of this query is not as expected,which displays zero records,.How this partial/full text search is possible using plainto_tsquery?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did just the same sequence of commands on 9.2 and got this result:
`SELECT * FROM fts WHERE body_tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('english','hellow world')` => 0 records returned. 
`SELECT * FROM fts WHERE body_tsvector @@ plainto_tsquery('english','hello world')` => 3 records returned.
Note the `w` character in first query, i guess it's just typo, but without this typo it just works fine.

Comment: Now i corrected the question.

Comment: Corrected query returns 0 results for corrected dataset, which is correct behaviour, but what you expect ?

Comment: I mean partial text search ,ie returns all three records.These each record includes at least one sub key,ie first in first 2 'hello' word is there and 'welcome' word in 3rd record.

Comment: @Dfr, Just like out put of this query  SELECT *
FROM fts
WHERE body_tsvector @@ to_tsquery('hellow | welcome')  ,Is this possible with plainto_tsquery?

Comment: Just as Chris already answered, this is not possible with `plainto_tsquery`, this function only AND's words in phrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting `plainto_tsquery` to perform an `|` (OR) query. But [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-controls.html) state:

> plainto_tsquery transforms unformatted text querytext to tsquery. The text is parsed and normalized much as for to_tsvector, then the & (AND) Boolean operator is inserted between surviving words.

So to do what you want you must parse your text yourself, then create a ts_query with the `|` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM fts 
WHERE body_tsvector @@ to_tsquery('english','hello | welcome');
```